# What is the most efficient way to iterate over all rows in R?

Tags: r

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){

if (df2$FLAG[i]==0) {df2$AGE[i]<-50}}
```

`df2` is a data frame with around 500,000 rows. So this takes a lot of time to run. 
Is there a way to optimize this in R?

Comment: Try `df2[df2$FLAG == 0, "AGE"] <- 50`

Comment: As indicated by David's comment, in R it's mostly the most efficient way not to iterate or loop at all but to use vectorized functions instead.

Comment: Thanks guys. Really appreciate. Big learning here.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Post it as an answer.